# How to propertly comment a PHP file based on GNU/GPL source

Tags: php, header, licensing

My question is pretty simple. I have an application based on another application delivered with GNU/GPL 2.0 license (in short: changed code that I will deliver on same license and new name). How my php files header should look like to make everything fine (don't break GNU/GPL 2.0 license). Example would be great.

### Here is a good example:

```
/**
 * @package     GovArticle.Administrator
 * @subpackage  com_govarticle.layouts
 * @author      Artur Stępień (artur@example.pl)
 * @copyright   (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 * @copyright   (C) 2015 - Fundacja PCJ Otwarte Źródła
 * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-standalone.html   
 * @link        http://dostepny.joomla.pl
 * 
 * Based on com_content layouts from Joomla!
 */
```

(based on [pear.php.net sample file](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php))

Double `@copyrights` is to mark who has copyrights to the original code. There could be also more then one `@author` tags to show who is author of the original source (in my case there was no original author, just copyrights mark).

Comment: Hi there! Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it is not a direct, programming related issue, but rather about licensing. You may be able to get an answer at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their on-topic page too. :D

Comment: It is a programming related issue. Most of us build software based on GNU/GPL source of other vendors. That software have to be property commented. And I'm not talking about all languages.

Comment: Nope. Software licensing is off-topic. Besides, you'd probably get a better answer at Open Source anyways.

Comment: The question was not about licensing. It was about creating correct php file header to mark previous author, copyrights owner . This docblock should be compatible with phpDocumentor. No lawyer will answer it better then experienced PHP programmer.

Comment: Exactly. It's an attribution issue that arises from software licensing, which is off-topic. Still encourage you to go to Open Source.

Comment: @Mathias-S links pointed me to the correct format so I got my answer. I did also add the sample correct header to my question so all will now how to do it. Creating another question in different section would be a waste of time for users and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU/GPL 2.0 doesn't require a specific documentation style, but [recommends that you include something like the following text in every source file](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html):

> This file is part of Foobar.
>
> Foobar is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>       it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>       the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
>       (at your option) any later version.
>
> Foobar is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>       but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>       MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
>       GNU General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>       along with Foobar.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

You may not need such as long notice in every file, see [Copyright notices/disclaimers in source files](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19649/copyright-notices-disclaimers-in-source-files), and what you've shown might be enough.

If you wish to use a standard way of documenting your code, you can use [phpDocumentor (phpDoc)](http://phpdoc.org/).

[PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) has a good [sample file](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php) of how you can document your code.

EDIT: You should also attribute the original author if you use third-party GPL code in your own program, see Flosculus' comment below.

Comment: Its probably worth saying something about the `author` tag, should it include the author of the original work?.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the example at pear.php.net, that lead me to the best method.

Comment: This is wrong. The GPL has fairly stringent requirements to assert copyright, including the existence of a copyright header.

Comment: Zizouz212: He already has one, so it's enough. According to [GNU's GPL howto](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html), a longer statement is _recommended_, but a simple copyright notice (such as “Copyright 2015 - Name”) and information about the license is enough. I've updated my answer accordingly.